# Pass function to element .data() while triggering .changeData event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to set the .data() of an element like so:

`$(elm).data('key', my_function() );`

The problem is that although my_function returns a string, .data() doesn't seem to wait until it's returned before setting it.

Also, even if I switch out my_function() for a test string, this doesn't trigger my 'changeData' event. I could manually trigger it, but I run into the same timing issue as above.

What is the proper way of setting the data as the returned value of the function, and trigger the changeData event.

*EDIT*

my_function() does a bunch of things, including $.each and $.ajax, eventually returning an object or string.

Comment: If the data value you want relies on`$.ajax`, you need to move the `$(elm).data` call into your AJAX success/failure handlers.

Comment: @joews - After some more investigation, this seems to be the better way. If you make this comment your answer, I will mark it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the issue here is that your my_function() call is not asynchronous. Perhaps you can most the code for that function as well.

Comment: I've updated the question to mention that my_function() is synchronous.

Comment: I'm a little confused are saying above that you `my_function` can return a string or an object? I'm pretty sue data attribute can only take a string.

Comment: @Showcaselfloyd jQuery's `$.fn.data` can take any kind of value